# Alinhar dados tbody com theady

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, table

Tenho dados consumidos por uma API para popular uma table no html, eles estão vindos OK, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o alinhamento entre o theady e o tbody que populo em tempo de execução, vocês poderiam me ajudar?

Ela está ficando assim na tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue baixo codigos:

```
        <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <!--<th>Ride in group</th>
                    <th>Day of the week</th>
                    <th>Posts</th>-->
                    <th>Albums</th>
                    <!--<th>Photos</th>-->
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <!--<tr>
                    <td class="td-username"></td>
                    <td class="td-name"></td>
                    <td class="td-mail"></td>
                    <td class="td-city"></td>
                    <td class="td-ride"></td>
                    <td class="td-day"></td>
                    <td class="td-posts"></td>
                    <td class="td-albuns"></td>
                    <td class="td-photos"></td>
                </tr>-->
            </tbody>
        </table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var vUsers  = [];
    var vAlbums = [];
    var length;


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({ url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
            async: false,
            success: function(data1) {
                vUsers = data1;                                
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);

                return false; 
            }
        });


        $.ajax({url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos',
            async: false,
            success: function(data2) {
                vAlbums = data2;            
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);

                return false; 
            }
        });



        var table = document.getElementById('table');

        function contaAlbums(lineId) {
            length = 0;

            vAlbums.forEach(function(album) {
                if (album.userId == lineId) {
                    length++;
                }
            });

            return length;
        };


        vUsers.forEach((line) => {
          var lineId   = line.id;

          var tr       = document.createElement('tr');
          var username = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = line.username;
          var name     = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = line.name;
          var email    = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = line.email;
          var city     = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = line.address.city;

          var albumCount = contaAlbums(lineId);

          //alert(albumCount)

          var tdAlbums = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = albumCount;


          //$('.td-username').append(name);

          tr.append(username, name, email, city, tdAlbums);
          table.append(tr);
        });     
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

São dois os motivos que geram o seu problema.

Primeiro motivo é que para cada `<td>` criada você está perdendo a sua referencia. Quando faz:

```
var username = document.createElement('td').innerHtml = line.username;
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
var username = document.createElement('td').innerHtml;
username = line.username;
```

Ou seja a variável `username` não chega a referenciar a `<td>` recém criada, `username` recebe o valor da propriedade `.innerHtml` e logo em seguida passa a referenciar a string `line.username` e isso se repete em `username`, `name` , `email`, `city` e `tdAlbums`. Implicando que ao fazer:

```
tr.append(username, name, email, city, tdAlbums);
```

Ao de adicionar cinco `<td>` você está adicionando na primeira célula uma string formada pelas strings `username`, `name` , `email`, `city` e `tdAlbums`.

O segundo problema se dá ao consertar o primeiro:

```
var username = document.createElement('td');
username.innerHtml = line.username;
```

Ao setar a propriedade [`username.innerHtml`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) você esta trocando o conteúdo do elemento por uma string e novamente isso se repete para `username`, `name` , `email`, `city` e `tdAlbums` e novamente ao fazer:

```
tr.append(username, name, email, city, tdAlbums);
```

Você não estará adicionando cinco `<td>` a `<tr>` mas estará adicionando mais uma vez na primeira célula uma string formada pelas strings `username`, `name` , `email`, `city` e `tdAlbums`.

Para concertar seu código basta atribuir as variáveis suas devidas referências:

```
var username = document.createElement('td');
var name = document.createElement('td');    
var email = document.createElement('td');    
var city = document.createElement('td');
var tdAlbums = document.createElement('td').
```

E então use a propriedade [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) ao invés de `innerHtml`:

```
username.innerText = line.username;
name.innerText = line.name;
email.innerText = line.email;    
city.innerText = line.address.city;
tdAlbums.innerHtml = albumCount;
```

Ou no seu código:

```js
var vUsers = [];
var vAlbums = [];
var length;


$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    async: false,
    success: function(data1) {
      vUsers = data1;
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(thrownError);

      return false;
    }
  });


  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos',
    async: false,
    success: function(data2) {
      vAlbums = data2;
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(thrownError);

      return false;
    }
  });



  var table = document.getElementById('table');


  function contaAlbums(lineId) {
    length = 0;

    vAlbums.forEach(function(album) {
      if (album.userId == lineId) {
        length++;
      }
    });

    return length;
  };


  vUsers.forEach((line) => {
    var lineId = line.id;
    var albumCount = contaAlbums(lineId);

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    var username = document.createElement('td');
    var name = document.createElement('td');
    var email = document.createElement('td');
    var city = document.createElement('td');
    var tdAlbums = document.createElement('td');

    username.innerText = line.username;
    name.innerText = line.name;
    email.innerText = line.email;
    city.innerText = line.address.city;
    tdAlbums.innerText = albumCount;



    tr.append(username, name, email, city, tdAlbums);
    table.append(tr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Albums</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bom dia Augusto, tudo bem? Cara funcionou perfeitamente a parte da table, mas ainda continuo com o mesmo problema do contador na função contaAlbums() e me surgiu um novo problema agora também, se você perceber, coloquei no AJAX async: false por causa das variaveis globais que preciso tratar fora do AJAX, mas está demorando demais, existe uma outra forma de PEGAR essas variaveis fora do AJAX sem que tenha que usar o ASYNC?

Comment: O JQuery Ajax tem a opção [`async: false`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) para o caso de precisar fazer requisição síncronas. Dê uma olhada no [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) e mais fácil de usar que *$Ajax*.

Comment: Quanto ao contador eu nem analisei o restante do código eu me foquei no que estava na pergunta que era sobre alinhamento da tabela.

Comment: Olhando os dados por cima, acredito que se pegar o `username` e contar quantas ocorrência  surjam na lista será a quantidade de álbuns.

Comment: Augusto desculpe a ignorancia de não saber sobre o Axios, mas to sem tempo de estudar, preciso entregar isso até o fim da tarde de hoje to sem tempo. Quanto ao contador estava passando o indice errado no IF dentro da função.
Agora preciso resolver esse problema mesmo do ASYNC do AJAX

Comment: Entendi, não e melhor abrir outra pergunta específica sobre o contador pois o escopo dessa pergunta aqui é formatação de tabela e o formato do site não permite essa mudança de escopo numa pergunta depois de respondida.

Comment: Sim é verdade Augusto, vou abrir, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como você utilizou o `.append()` para colocar elementos no `tr`, você pode utilizá-lo para colocar o texto nos elementos `td` que o resultado sairá correto. Por exemplo:

```
var name = document.createElement('td');
name.append(line.name);
```

E o resultado:

[image: Tabela preenchida corretamente]